# Interface files missing from downloaded SDK source code

Tags: android, sdk, android-sdk-tools, android-package-managers

I try to step in the sdk source as depth as possible.

Let's say I step into my sdk source, `~/Android/Sdk/sources/android-24/android/app/ApplicationPackageManager.java`:

```
import android.content.pm.IPackageManager;
```

But no such file `IPackageManager.java` inside `pm` directory:

```
[xiaobai@localhost pm]$ pwd
/home/xiaobai/Android/Sdk/sources/android-24/android/content/pm
[xiaobai@localhost pm]$ ls I*
InstrumentationInfo.java  IntentFilterVerificationInfo.java
[xiaobai@localhost pm]$
```

Why is it not there? Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: I've edited your question to not look like a resource request

Answer (score 1):

IPackageManager is an aidl file. It appears aidl files are not included when you download the source code package via the SDK tools.

You can browse the online repository to find it though: [IPackageManager.aidl](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/content/pm/IPackageManager.aidl).
You can view the file content in a browser.

Comment: Is there any reason aidl file excluded from sdk source ?

Comment: @林果皞 It is an Interface Definition Language file, my guess is that google does not consider these files to be source code. Read more here https://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html